# Xaringan: Math renders as inline code in footnote class

Tags: r, xaringan

Using the default Xaringan CSS, if $math$ is placed in a footnote, it appears to be rendered as `inline code`, rather than rendering as math. I was not able to find information about this - is this just a natural limitation in Xaringan or remark.js? Or perhaps I am doing something wrong?

See basic example below:

```
# A Test

- This is a test<sup>1</sup>

.footnote[<sup>1</sup> This includes $\delta+\frac{2}{3}$ math.]
```

This will render the math between the $$ as if it were between backticks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[UPDATE 17/12/2019] Another way to circumvent this is to replace the maths expression `$\delta+\frac{2}{3}$` with `\(\delta+\frac{2}{3}\)` which bypasses any need for `remark.js` to convert `$` and thus avoiding the bug there.

---

Yes I noticed this too. I think somehow `remark.js` is interfering with mathjax but I don't really know. To get around this I use the html code directly instead. So below should work:

```
# A Test

- This is a test<sup>1</sup>

<span class="footnote"><sup>1</sup> This includes $\delta+\frac{2}{3}$ math.</span>
```

[UPDATE]
The explanation of why this happens can be found [here](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/213). TL;DR: `remark.js` removes the brackets necessary for mathjax to detect the maths.

Yihui also provided an alternate hack if the use of `.footnote[]` is desirable which involves adding the brackets to the inline math code:

`` .footnote[<sup>1</sup> This includes `\\(\delta+\frac{2}{3}\\)` math.] ``

Comment: Hi Kunoichi Emi, would you help me debug it? :) The JS code to deal with math expressions is here: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/blob/153684b9a4662903e34c7e8397dca845c2a2be89/inst/rmarkdown/templates/xaringan/resources/default.html#L68-L85

Comment: You knew how to solve it didn't you Yihui, but you gave me enough hint for me to figure it out myself ;)
I have to admit that I had no idea how to solve it but I'm surprised that I actually figured it out after your hint. 
But my current hack will impact anything code written starting and ending in round brackets - will explain on github issues.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't really know what the problem was. I can certainly figure it out by myself, but thought it would be a good exercise for other people (and I have already had too much other work to do). Anyway, thanks again for the investigation: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/213

Comment: None of the presented solutions work for me; has something changed?

Comment: The method described by [@YihuiXie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie) in GitHub still works: `.footnote[<sup>1</sup> This includes \`\\(\delta+\frac{2}{3}\\)\` math.]`